# Stop background music using silverlight on Win10 Mobile

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

Hey I have searched around and found many solutions (that work) for WP 7, WP 8 and WP 8.1. Now that win 10 mobile is publicly released I tested my app, and quite some features are not supported anymore.

But for the question in hand. I have silverlight app and if music is playing in the background, the user is prompted by a messagebox:

```
     public bool BackgroundMusicAllowed()
    {
        bool allowed = true;

        //you can check a stored property here and return false if you want to disable all bgm

        if (!MediaPlayer.GameHasControl)
        {
            //ask user about background music
            MessageBoxResult mbr = MessageBox.Show("press ok if you’d like to use this app’s background music (this will stop your current music playback)", "use app background music?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            
            if (mbr != MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                allowed = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //Stop Audio in two different ways
                Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.Stop();
                Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop();
                Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            }
        }
        return allowed;
    }
```

The code would then return `true` if the user wants the app to start playing music and I would do it.

## The Issue

On Win10 Mobile this does not work however. So what to do to turn off the background music from other apps with silverlight on Win 10 Mobile?